# How to filter list using date?

Tags: apex

I want to filter the items in the list based on its date.How to achieve this?

```
public List<SfResults> listCon {get; set;}
public PageReference filterSearchResults()
{
//dateFilter is the radioButton value 
for (SfResults result:listCon ) {
    //filter by date
    if(dateFilter=='week')
    {
     //if lastModifiedDate is within a week then add this to FilteredList
    }
    else if (dateFilter=='month')
    {
     //if lastModifiedDate is within a month then add this to FilteredList
    }
    else if (dateFilter=='year')
    {
         //if lastModifiedDate is within a year then add this to FilteredList
    }
    //if no dateFilter is selected
    else
    {
     //add all to the list
    }      
}
public class SfResults {
        public Date lastModifiedDate {get;set;}     
}
```

Comment: Do u want to sort all elements of a list by some date field?

Comment: Suggest you make the title and detail of your question consistent: title says "sort" and code says "filter".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accomplish the filtering would be to use dynamic SOQL and append the appropriate [Date Literal](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/officetoolkit/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) expression to the where term.

Assuming that approach is not convenient (or the unfiltered data is needed elsewhere), the filtering can be done in Apex code like this:

```
private List<SfResults> filter(List<SfResults> results) {
    List<SfResults> filtered = new List<SfResults>();
    Date t = Date.today();
    for (SfResults r : results) {
        Date d = r.lastModifiedDate
        if (dateFilter == 'week') {
            if (d > t.addDays(-7)) {
                filtered.add(r);
            }
        } else if (dateFilter == 'month') {
            if (d > t.addMonths(-1)) {
                filtered.add(r);
            }
        } else if (dateFilter == 'year') {
            if (d > t.addYears(-1)) {
                filtered.add(r);
            }
        } else {
            // Add all to the list if no filter selected
            filtered.add(r);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In SOQL you can use `ORDER BY`

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm

If you need it in code use `Comparable Interface`

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_comparable.htm

It allows you sort list using any value you want! :)

Comment: I dont want to sort list items ..I want to add the to anotherlist depending on the value of datefilter variable.If datefilter is set for a week then only items whose lastModifiedDate is within last week will be added to list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort your list element by some Date field then you can use `Comparable interface`.

[This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927109/sort-objects-in-arraylist-by-date) can help you to understand how to implement this interface and override `compareTo` method.